# user has more than max_user_connections active connections

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have laragon as server on local machine. I am working on Laravel project. I used to face following error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1203] User test_develop already has more than
>   'max_user_connections' active connections (SQL: select * from
>   information_schema.tables where table_schema = test_develop and
>   table_name = version)

I tried to find its solution on Google but nothing useful found. Enabling infinite connections in mysql setting is not a good idea. I am also trying to find where MYSQL is making so many connections and I always used to restart server for temporarily solving problem.

But now it has started coming on online site as well so my question is what could be its permanent solution? Any suggestions please?

Comment: Try persistent connections

Comment: @davidbaumann Will it put any performance impact on server if I make persistent connection?

Comment: @Jass do not go for persistent connections; post your my.cnf file usually in /etc/my.cnf, I don't know about laragon but your mysql settings might be too low?

Comment: @ahmad I do not see my.cnf file in complete Laragon folder but there is my.ini file. is it same?

Comment: Yes, it might be the same I guess